# Elasticsearch - Java RestHighLevelClient - how to get all documents using scroll api

Tags: java, elasticsearch

In my index in Elasticsearch I saved about 30000 entities. I'd like to get all ids of them using RestHighLevelClient. I've read that the best way to do it is to use scroll api. However when I do it I recieve only about 10 entities instead of 30k. How to solve this

```
final class ElasticRepo {
    private final RestHighLevelClient restHighLevelClient;

List<ListingsData> getAllListingsDataIds() {
        val request = new SearchRequest(ELASTICSEARCH_LISTINGS_INDEX);
        request.types(ELASTICSEARCH_TYPE);
        val searchSourceBuilder = new SearchSourceBuilder()
                .query(matchAllQuery())
                .fetchSource(new String[]{"listing_id"}, new String[]{"backoffice_data", "search_and_match_data"});
        request.source(searchSourceBuilder);
        request.scroll(TimeValue.timeValueMinutes(3));
        return executeQuery(request);
    }

 private List<ListingsData> executeQuery(final SearchRequest searchQuery) {
        try {
            val hits = restHighLevelClient.search(searchQuery, RequestOptions.DEFAULT).getHits().getHits();
            return Arrays.stream(hits).map(SearchHit::getSourceAsString).map(ElasticRepo::toListingsData).collect(Collectors.toList());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new RuntimeException("");
        }
    }

}
```

And when I do it executeQuery returns only about 11 entites. How to solve that, how to obtain all documents in index ?

Comment: if you find one of these answers usefull you should accept one of them

Comment: Ok, I haven't tested it yet

Answer (score 10, accepted):

try to follow this example, I am using this code and it works:

```
        String query = "your query here";

        QueryBuilder matchQueryBuilder = QueryBuilders.boolQuery().must(new QueryStringQueryBuilder(query));

        SearchSourceBuilder searchSourceBuilder = new SearchSourceBuilder();

        searchSourceBuilder.query(matchQueryBuilder);

        searchSourceBuilder.size(5000); //max is 10000

        searchRequest.indices("your index here");

        searchRequest.source(searchSourceBuilder);

        final Scroll scroll = new Scroll(TimeValue.timeValueMinutes(10L));

        searchRequest.scroll(scroll);

        SearchResponse searchResponse = client.search(searchRequest);
            String scrollId = searchResponse.getScrollId();

        SearchHit[] allHits = new SearchHit[0];

        SearchHit[] searchHits = searchResponse.getHits().getHits();

        while (searchHits != null && searchHits.length > 0)
        {

            allHits = Helper.concatenate(allHits, searchResponse.getHits().getHits()); //create a function which concatenate two arrays

            SearchScrollRequest scrollRequest = new SearchScrollRequest(scrollId);

            scrollRequest.scroll(scroll);

            searchResponse = client.searchScroll(scrollRequest);

            scrollId = searchResponse.getScrollId();

            searchHits = searchResponse.getHits().getHits();

        }

        ClearScrollRequest clearScrollRequest = new ClearScrollRequest();
        clearScrollRequest.addScrollId(scrollId);
        ClearScrollResponse clearScrollResponse = client.clearScroll(clearScrollRequest);
```

Answer (score 2):

As part of Search API, by default the max documents retrieved is 10 unless the size field is specified.

The Search Scroll API documentation as part of Java REST High Level document has a nice sample code -> https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/master/java-rest-high-search-scroll.html